# Spring boot - How to provide environment variables to app context to avoid unit test failure

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a spring boot REST API app. I am using environment variables in `application.properties` file. Some settings are as shown below:

```
logging.level.springframework.web=${WEB_LOG_LEVEL}
logging.level.org.hibernate=${HIBERNATE_LOG_LEVEL}
```

In my unit test, I use annocation `@TestPropertySource("classpath:application-test.properties")`. However, when I run `mvn clean install`, build fails because of unit test failure. I provided the error log. When I ran in IDE, I can provide those environment vairables. Any suggestions on how to pass them in `mvn clean install`? Or any other approaches you would recommend? Thanks much in advance!

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to bind properties under 'logging.level.springframework.web' to org.springframework.boot.logging.LogLevel:

    Property: logging.level.springframework.web
    Value: ${WEB_LOG_LEVEL}
    Origin: class path resource [application.properties] - 44:35
    Reason: failed to convert java.lang.String to org.springframework.boot.logging.LogLevel (caused by java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant org.springframework.boot.logging.LogLevel.${WEB_LOG_LEVEL})

Action:

Update your application's configuration. The following values are valid:

    DEBUG
    ERROR
    FATAL
    INFO
    OFF
    TRACE
    WARN
```

Comment: It looks as though your `application-test.properties` file is not in the right place. It should be in `src/test/resources`.

Comment: Alternatively you can provide the values as system properties instead of environment variables, which you can do via the maven surefire plugin configuration. But why not have them hard coded in `application-test.properties` for your unit tests?

Comment: Thank you @tgdavies! You are right. I can hardcode it in my `application-test.properties` file. I applied one of the options that @xerx593 suggested 'Fallback`. It worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

We have *many* options!

*Best* is we (roughly) understand the [2 Externalized Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config) and [PropertySource](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-using-propertysource):

1. Leaving our `application.properties` as it is, we can:

   1. (As tgdavies commented), introduce `src/test/resources/application...`
      Here we can:

      - call it `application.properties`, and it will override (existing settings/"sensible") of `src/main/resources/application.properties`, then we don't need `@PropertySource` or `@Profile`s on our test.
      - call it `application_test.properties`, then work rather with `@Profile("test")` + `@ActiveProfiles("test")` (on our test class(es), with even higher precedence as the above).
      - *don't* use `@PropertySource` (`some_custom_name.properties` file) for this use case, it has *too low* precedence!

      ...in these properties we will write (without placeholders):

      ```properties
      logging.level.springframework.web=warn
      logging.level.org.hibernate=warn
      # or the log level(s) of our choice, overriding(!) the "main ones"
      ```
   2. `SET`/`EXPORT` these properties in our (dev) environment! (with our cli/OS dialog/MAVEN_OPTS/...)
   3. Using [`@TestPropertySource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.13/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/TestPropertySource.html) (2nd highest precedence, in spring-boot configuration hierarchy!, no profiles):

      - like (override property):

        ```
        @TestPropertySource(properties = "logging.level.springframework.web=warn", ...)
        ```
      - or (using/trying relaxed binding):

        ```
        @TestPropertySource(properties = "web.log.level=warn", ...)
        ```
      - or (using a file):

        ```
        @TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:/some/properties.properties", ...)
        ```
2. But a slight modification of our (src/main/...)`application.properties` can also be very helpful: Fallback! - looks like:

   ```properties
   logging.level.springframework.web=${WEB_LOG_LEVEL:warn}
   logging.level.org.hibernate=${HIBERNATE_LOG_LEVEL:warn}
   ```

   It tries for the environment variables, and falls back to `warn`. With this, we can omit `@PropertySource/@Profile` *and/or* an additional test-application-properties.

   And even better with [relaxed binding](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.relaxed-binding):

   ```properties
   logging.level.springframework.web=${web.log.level:warn}
   logging.level.org.hibernate=${hibernate.log.level:warn}
   ```

   This will accept the above environment variables, but also (previously defined)"properties" + fall back to "warn".
3. Conflict-free combinations of the proposed.
4. ... -> [Chapter 2](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config), [Relaxed Binding](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.relaxed-binding)(, [Profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.profiles)!) and [Spring Boot How To: Properties and Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.properties-and-configuration).

Comment: my two cents: using "environment variables" in `application.properties` file seems to be a bad idea - writing down something like `logging.level.springframework.web=${web.log.level:warn}` gives more flexibilty because it forces spring to check both system property `web.log.level` and environment variable `WEB_LOG_LEVEL`

Comment: yes, thank you, @AndreyB.Panfilov, of course: [relaxed binding](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.relaxed-binding!;)

Comment: @xerx593 Thank you so much for your detailed explaination, suggestion and helpful links to Spring documentation! I took your approach. It solved the issue! Really appreciate your response!

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov Thank you for your comments! You are right, I applied the approach that @xerx593 recommended in `application-test.properties` file. It worked. Thanks!